# Cross platform Mobile SDK development

Tags: android, ios, .net, swift, sdk

We have a product that provides set API (written in WEB API/C#) for third party software. We want to develop a mobile SDK for iOS and Android apps. So, other third party mobile applications can integrate our APIs easily.

It has to support native mobile apps, cross platform apps (eg: Xamarin) and HTML5 apps. I have been doing some investigation to see if it's possible to create a cross platform SDK that can support all mobile app frameworks. But couldn't find anything like that.

Initially thought about creating a Nuget package but that may not be able to use from native application development editors.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do such SDK using .net? If not what are the possible options? Thanks!

Comment: .Net means [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin) framework only. If you want Java/Kotlin Android devs or ObjC/Swift iOS devs, you'll have to provide packages for their respective platforms.

Comment: @MorrisonChang:  Do you know what are the most popular respective sdk platforms for ios and android? Will it need separate ones for each platforms such as ObjectiveC/Swift and java/Kotlin? Thanks.

Comment: Each third-party framework like: [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/), [Ionic](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework), Xamarin, [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) & others have pros/cons. Given that they all have to talk to their native mobile environment (Swift/iOS, Kotlin/Android), you write a native iOS library and a native Android library and then you/others build third-party framework shims for access. For examples see Ad SDKs like [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob) or [FB Audience](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads)